# SQL Filter otherwise duplicate entries based on a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
╔════════════╦═════════╦═══════════╗
║ Machine_ID  ║ User_ ID ║ User_Role  ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬═══════════╣
║ Mach_001    ║ N00001   ║         3  ║
║ Mach_001    ║ N00001   ║         4  ║
║ Mach_001    ║ N00002   ║         3  ║
║ Mach_001    ║ N00002   ║         2  ║
║ Mach_002    ║ N00001   ║         3  ║
║ Mach_002    ║ N00002   ║         3  ║
╚════════════╩═════════╩═══════════╝
```

I'm trying to get the the rows with the highest `User_Role` for each `Machine_ID` - `User_ID` as such:

```
╔════════════╦═════════╦═══════════╗
║ Machine_ID  ║ User_ID  ║ User_Role  ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬═══════════╣
║ Mach_001    ║ N00001   ║ 4          ║
║ Mach_001    ║ N00002   ║ 3          ║
║ Mach_002    ║ N00001   ║ 3          ║
║ Mach_002    ║ N00002   ║ 3          ║
╚════════════╩═════════╩═══════════╝
```

How do I go about doing this?  With my data, I could have many `Machine_ID`-`User_ID` duplicates with different `Role` levels, but I'd just like the highest role.

Edit:
Working off of Gordon Linoff's answer, I was able to get what I was looking for:

```
SELECT Machine_ID, User_ID, User_Role
FROM (SELECT ex_rt.*,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Machine_ID, User_ID, ORDER BY User_Role DESC) AS seqnum
      FROM ex_rt
     ) sub
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.3 JDBC4

Comment: What queries have you tried?  There are several tactics that could be used here...

Comment: TallTed, on you revision, you said you tweaked the format for clarity. (I'm trying to not sound rude, I'm just trying to improve my formatting skills) Was there something unclear about the way I had my tables formatted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most databases, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by machine_name, user_ID order by user_role desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, this didn't quite work, but I got it to run with a few minor edits.  Aliasing the inner query and the outer query both as t threw me off, so I renamed the outer query, and I partitioned by machine_id and user_id (sorry if my question was unclear on that)